# NPX issue-Path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: create-react-app, npx

I have an npx issue which causes my windows integration tests for my Create React App to fail.

```
npx create-react-app --scripts-version /tmp/tmp.jZbyogx2t1/react-scripts.tgz /tmp/tmp.jZbyogx2t1/test-app
```

It gives
NPX issue-Path must be a string. Received undefined

It worked pretty well till I upgraded CRA to latest and then it started breaking.

Anybody experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have also faced the same issue

Try

`npm cache clean --force`

then

`npm update`

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

copy the npx.cmd file from the path %AppData%\npm\node_modules\npm\bin to C:\Program Files\nodejs directory

Also in some instances, the npx is latest at the path %AppData%\Roaming\npm